# How to style & toggle notifications list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a nav bar using nav and li tags, including a notifications icon, I am trying to make notifications nested list to show notifications, and use JavaScript to toggle/hide the menu, so far no luck. I've been looking for snippets online to support my logic, but I am stuck in the styling part and the JavaScript functionality. code below:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1.32vmin;
}


/*
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
        border: 0.53vmin solid rgba(7, 67, 146, 0.17);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.33vmin 0.26vmin rgba(7, 67, 146, 0.17);
    }
    */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #074392;
  border-radius: 0vmin;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  height: 7.45vmin;
  background: #074392;
}

body {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.12vmin;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 3vmin;
}

h5 {
  margin: 2vmin 3vmin;
  position: absolute;
  width: 14.72vmin;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.65vmin;
  letter-spacing: 0.79vmin;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
}

nav {
  background-color: #074392;
  height: 7.42vmin;
  width: 100%;
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

img.logo {
  margin: 1.855vmin 3vmin;
  height: 3.5vmin;
  width: 7vmin;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 1.855vmin 2vmin;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li::before {
  content: " ";
  padding: 0vmin 0.5vmin;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  /*margin: 0vmin 1vmin;*/
  /*border-top-left-radius: 1.326vmin;
        border-top-right-radius: 1.326vmin;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1.326vmin;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1.326vmin;*/
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1;
}

.checkbtn {
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  margin: 1.855vmin 3vmin;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

#check:checked~ul {
  left: 0;
}

.dropdown {}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #074392;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0743922B;
  width: 37.5vmin;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  transform: translateX(-56%);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #0743922B;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Menu">menu</i>
          </label>
    <h5>LOGO</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="home.php"> <i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Home">home</i></a>
      </li>
      <!-- <li><a href="index.html"> <i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Notifications">notifications</i> </a> -->
      <li class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Notifications">notifications</i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
          <div><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
          <div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
          <div><a href="#">Link asasdasdasdasdasdsadsadasdasdasdasd asddasdas asd asd asd dasd asd</a></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="311.html"> <i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Tasks">task</i> </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="add.php"> <i class="material-symbols-rounded" style="font-size:3.5vmin;" title="Profile">person</i> </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ActiveTab.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/ToggleNotifications.js"></script>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>Example Page</h1>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default set a `display: none` on the dropdown element and set a `display: block` on the hover pseudo-class of the dropdown element so when a hover event is triggered the dropdown appears.
Also, you can use `classList.toggle` method to remove if exists or to add if not exist the class.

Remove
Just add the following to the `.css`:

```css
#myDropdown {
  display: none;
}

#myDropdown.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Remove `onclick="myFunction()"`. And replace the `.js` with:

```
const myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown')
addEventListener('click', event => {
  let dropbtn = event.target.closest('button.dropbtn')
  if (!dropbtn) return myDropdown.classList.remove('show')
  console.log('hii')
  myDropdown.classList.toggle('show')
})
```

Comment: it doesn't work on pressing the bell button, it only drops down if i press anywhere else on screen (on/off)

Comment: i removed the negation from the if condition and it works only if i press it for on/off. i want it to be closed on any where clicked on screen too

Comment: may i ask why the drop down menu is not shown correctly below the button? why overlapping with the nav bar?

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the solution as correct so other people who have the same problem see the correct solution.

Comment: done and thanks again!
now about the DDL positioning?

Comment: By all the code you have provided I'm just able to see this: https://imgur.com/mRG91J8. What do you mean by overlapping?

Comment: in order for the styling to appear properly i used this 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/common.css"/>
sorry for excluding it by mistake

Comment: You can upload all your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ and send the link to me so I can try to fix it. I'd love to.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!:)
I figured it out, I just used top: px; command in css to adjust the problem.
thanks again & again man

Comment: You're always welcome.